# How to make the font-size smaller based on the dynamic amount of characters inserted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am trying to handle the font-size on the dynamic amount of the characters like now i have set of characters with the font-size:40px on increasing the characters the font-size should be reduced within the space.

So this is my html code:

```
<table width="620"><tr><td width="30%"></td><td ><span style="font-size:40px; font-size: 1.8vw; font-weight:bold;">BhairavPrasadVishwanatham</span><br/><span class="text-danger" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">VISITOR </span><br/><span class="h4 m-t-mini">XYZ</span><span class="clearfix text-center m-t-large"></span><br/><span class="h4 m-b-mini text-center">To See:</span><br/><span class="h3 text-bold m-b-small text-center">ABC</span><td></tr><tr><td></td><td><span class="clearfix"><br/><span style="font-size:16px;">Valid Thru: 26-05-2016</span><br/><br/></td></tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Now I need the name:BhairavprasadVishwanatham should be automatically adjust the font according to the number characters entered like:-

if i entered more than 9 characters then the font should be reduced and fitted the td.

Comment: First of all, please format you HTML proberly! Second, what have you even tried? To me it looks like you have done nothing...

Comment: I've formatted your HTML and it appears it has several issues. Fix those first.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your span eg:

```
<span class="h3 text-bold m-b-small text-center checkSize">ABC</span><td></tr><tr><td></td><td><span class="clearfix"><br/><span style="font-size:16px;">Valid Thru: 26-05-2016</span>
```

then jquery :

```
$(".checkSize").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html().length > 20) $(this)..css( "font-size", '5px' )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick dirty pure js solution

```
<span class="decreaseFontSize">
    This is your text you want to reduce
</span>
<script>
var el = document.querySelector('.decreaseFontSize');
var text = el.innerText || el.textContent;
var endFontSize = 40;
if(text.length<9){
   endFontSize = 40;
}
if(text.length < 5){
   endFontSize = 20
}
...
el.style.fontSize = endFontSize+'px';
</script>
```

However what you try to achieve is probably to make text always fit in one line and automatically scale not based on characters amount but on characters width (w is wider then i in all non monotype fonts). With that normal image might come handy, let's say text saved as svg will resize to proper size, however you still need to estimate width of letters.